# AngularJS: How to use ngclipboard with ng-show/ng-hide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm implementing a function that when I click a button, some text gets copied. I do not want to show the text, and I don't want to mess up my layout.

My attempt is to use `ngclipboard` and `ng-hide`, following the tutorial of this post

https://medium.com/@kris.stange2015/use-ngclipboard-with-an-angular-ng-repeat-directive-398d4eaf2c83

My code works very similar to the post

```
<button type="button"
            class="button button--info"
            ng-if="!some_iter.show"
            ngclipboard
            data-clipboard-target="#someTag{{$index}}"
            ngclipboard-success="ctrl.onClipboardSuccess(e)"
            ngclipboard-error="ctrl.onClipboardError(e)">Copy Invite Link</button>
<input class='input-hide' id="someTag{{$index}}" ng-value="some_iter.url"></input>
```

I ran into the exact problem he or she mentioned, which is the value cannot be captured when hiding the `input`. I tried the working method and it messes up my layout. My questions:

1. why wouldn't it work if I hide the value? As far as I know, `ng-hide` only works with css, and why wouldn't `display: none` and `visibility: none` work? The component is still there, right?
2. How to make sure my layout is not messed up if I use `opacity: 0`? Basically how do I not have a weird empty spot where users can still somehow drag and copy the text (it's not crucial, but I don't like it)

Comment: Okay nvm, using `data-clipboard-text="{{some_iter.url}}"` can avoid the `input` altogether

Comment: You can answer your own question for future readers and mark it as the accepted answer if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out. Instead of dealing with the input field, we can directly inject data into the ngclipboard using

```
<button type="button"
            class="button button--info"
            ng-if="!some_iter.show"
            ngclipboard
            data-clipboard-text="{{some_iter.url}}"
            ngclipboard-success="ctrl.onClipboardSuccess(e)"
            ngclipboard-error="ctrl.onClipboardError(e)">Copy Invite Link</button>
```

and we can remove

```
<input class='input-hide' id="someTag{{$index}}" ng-value="some_iter.url"></input>
```